# Django Apache DocumentRoot?

Tags: django, apache, document-root

What directory must the DocumentRoot in Apache be set to run a Django app is it the static directory but that does not work? Thanks to all for the help in advance.

Comment: The document root has nothing to do in a Django app.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 9):

You point to project root; where `wsgi.py` file is. From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/):

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /path/to/venv
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Static file are configured separately. Details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files). Example (again, from docs):

```
Alias /robots.txt /path/to/mysite.com/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /path/to/mysite.com/static/favicon.ico

Alias /media/ /path/to/mysite.com/media/
Alias /static/ /path/to/mysite.com/static/

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking what should the Apache directive `DocumentRoot` should be

Answer (score 1):

When using Django, the `DocumentRoot` directive is not needed.

Under the traditional approach to web sites, where Apache serves pre-written HTML files, Apache uses `DocumentRoot`, say

```
DocumentRoot = /var/www/website
```

so that when a user request a resource like `users/profile.html`, it can map that to the filesystem file `/var/www/website/users/profile.html`, which is an actual file.

In Django, by contrast, there are no pre-written HTML files for Apache to find.  Instead, all requests are directed to Django directly, which constructs the HTML file dynamically and returns that.  Thus, Apache doesn't need a `DocumentRoot`, it needs to know the location of Django's WSGI application file `wsgi.py`, which is the "gateway" for sending HTTP requests to Django so that it can construct the right HTML file to return.  This is specifed by the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive and associated Apache configuration; e.g.

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

as given by the Django documentation on [deploying Django with Apache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

**TL;DR:**  You don't need `DocumentRoot`, you need `WSGIScriptAlias` for Django.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are asking for this:

```
ServerAdmin example@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```